# I2C rpi i/o error

Tags: i2c

I'm trying to send multiple bytes of data to an arduino from the RPi but when using :

```
Def writenumbersecond(values) :
    bus.write_byte(0x04, values) 
    Return None
```

But when calling this data it gives an I/O error and therefore not sending any daya because of this. It doesnt seem for allow the sending of multiple bits. Any advice on this would be much appreciated. 
Edit:
Bus.write_byte(0x04,values)
I/O error: [errno 5] input/output error

Comment: You should include the exact text of the error.

Comment: Included the error

Comment: The clue is in the name of the function, **write_byte**.

Comment: @joan So would this require write_byte_data?

Comment: Afraid not.  You need to look at the documentation for the SMBus commands.  You probably want to use write_block_data which allows up to 32 bytes to be written to a register.

Comment: Actually I'm being a bit unfair.  I'd forgotten that the SMBus commands are poorly documented and (in my opinion) poorly designed.  What data are you actually trying to send to your device?

Comment: I am trying to send data from a csv file, which is in the format country, boolean. Ive extracted the boolean value and trying send that. I was thinking about using write_byte_data but uncertain what the cmd argument is

Comment: See if write_i2c_block_data is available and send the first byte in the cmd parameter, and the rest of the bytes in a list as the third parameter.  That is probably the best you can do given the SMBus commands.  write_block_data is similar but also sends a byte count which will upset your device.